# Unable to use beautifulsoup find(class_) attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to locate a specific class. I can use the same statement with find(id) but class returns nothing so prettify errors out

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://abcnews.go.com/Politics"
page = requests.get(URL)

# Testing Write to file from bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="abcnews")
newresults = results.prettify
prettyresults = str(newresults)

abc_file = open("abc_pol.html", "wt")
n = abc_file.write(prettyresults)
abc_file.close()

# Listings

abclistings = soup.find(class_ = "subNav_outer")
newlistings = abclistings.prettify
prettylistings = str(abclistings)

abc_listings_file = open("ABC_Listings.html", "wt")
w = abc_listings_file.write(prettylistings)
abc_listings_file.close()


print(prettylistings)
```

```
$ /home/nicholas/Documents/Dev/Py/GN/bin/python /home/nicholas/Documents/Dev/Py/GN/abcnews.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicholas/Documents/Dev/Py/GN/abcnews.py", line 20, in <module>
    newlistings = abclistings.prettify
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'
```

Comment: Typo.  The class has TWO underscores, not one: `subNav__outer`.

Comment: You should also *call* `.prettify()`; your `prettyresults` should look rather unexpected currently.

Answer (score 0):

Things to correct in your code:

1. You are using the incorrect class name. Use `soup.find(class_="subNav__outer")` instead of `soup.find(class_="subNav_outer")`.
2. Better to use `results.prettify()` instead of `results.prettify` and similarly `abclistings.prettify()` instead of `abclistings.prettify`. You won't need to typecast the result into `str` because `prettify()` itself returns an `str`.

Here is a more optimized version of your code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://abcnews.go.com/Politics"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="abcnews")
with open("abc_pol.html", "wt") as f:
    f.write(results.prettify())

abclistings = soup.find(class_="subNav__outer")
with open("ABC_Listings.html", "wt") as f:
    f.write(abclistings.prettify())
```